# Can I worship Krishna to fullfill my material desires?

Tags: krishna, worship

I wanted to know that can I worship the supreme lord (Krishna) to fulfill my material desire?
I know that those who want moksha worship him, but is worshiping him for material desires also possible?

I don't want moksha, I am 16 years old. I was just curious to know about my religion, so I read Gita. Now I found out that I am not fit for moksha, but I want to fulfill my material goals and desires. I am now curious to know that Krishna being the supreme lord, will he grant the material desires of people?

Comment: The title of the question is confusing, change it to *Can I worship Krishna to fulfill my material desires?*

Comment: By Krishna do you include Vishnu also,or only the Krishna form?

Comment: "By Krishna do you include Vishnu also,or only the Krishna form" Krishna is just an avatar of Vishnu and nothing else.

Comment: You can worship any god to fulfill your material desires. The quickiest way is via Shiva.

Comment: Read what Krishna says https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/88

Comment: _Now I found out that I am not fit for moksha_ you are not the one who will decide this. Leave it on Lord :-)

Comment: And as you said you have read BG, you might have understood that our goal should be something else and not material goals

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course.Sri Krishna says in the Gita:

> 7.16 O Arjuna, foremost of the Bharata dynasty, four classes of people of virtuous deeds adore Me: the afflicted, the seeker of Knowledge, the seeker of wealth and the man of Knowledge.

Please notice that **the Afflicted and the wealth-seeker both worship Him for fulfilling material** **desires**.Wealth('Artha') does not just meant accumulated money alone. It means wish and desire also according to sanskritdictionary.com:

> अर्थः [In some of its senses from अर्थ्; in others from ऋ-थन् Uṇ.2.4; अर्थते ह्यसौ अर्थिभिः Nir.] 1 Object, purpose, end and aim; **wish**, **desire**;

The Lord therefore Himself says that He is worshipped for fulfilling the desires. He also says:

> 4.11 Whoever resortt to Me **in any manner**, **in the same manner do I favour them;** men experience Me alone in different ways, O Arjuna.

The Glory of the Name of Krishna is also sung in various scriptures. Like:

> sarvAni nAmAni hitasya rajan ***sarvArtha-siddhai*** tu bhavanti pumsah/tasmad yathestam khalu krishna-nAma sarveshu kAleshu japeta bhaktyA// Meaning : O King !All the names of the Lord fulfills all desires of men. So it is enough to chant the name of Krishna with devotion.(Sri Sri Krishna-Nama-Mahima, Omkarnath Rachanavali,vol.14,, page 394).

The Padma-Purana (Uttara Khanda) says

> jnAnam cha daiva-mahatAm **sarva-siddhipradam phalam** : (The name of Krishna) fulfills all desires. (Ibid. page 425).

In Srimad-Bhagavatam(4/8/19), Suniti asked her son Dhruva to worship Sri Hari as get back his kingdom:

> My dear boy, whatever has been spoken by Suruci, your stepmother, although very harsh to hear, is correct. Therefore, if you desire at all to acquire the same throne as your stepbrother Uttama, give up your envious attitude and immediately try to follow the instructions of your stepmother. Without further delay, you must engage yourself in worshiping the lotus feet of Sri Hari.

Narada also adviced the same to Dhruva(4/8/40). Its well known that Hari or VAsudeva are alternative names of Krishna and Vishnu is just another form of Him. Dhruva got back His kingdom by getting boon from Sri Vishnu.

So the answer to your question according to the scriptures is: Yes, Of course. We must however remember that Sri Krishna is God and  He will surely not fulfill any evil desires that causes harm to anyone like some tantric worships do.

Comment: I've read it in the Gita that, people who worship the Demi god's for fulfillment of desires, their desires are fullfilles soon but a person who worship the supreme lord, doesn't gets his desires fulfilled... That's why he is hard to worship... Is that true? Or I have misunderstood it...

Comment: @Kartik Gita does not contain any word like demi-gods.Please read any good translation.What you are saying is not correct.GitaPress has many versions of Gita and many translations are available online also.

Comment: I've read the bhagavad Gita as it is. Is not the suitable one?

Comment: Please tell me the best commentary on Gita for a 16 year old guy. Thanks !

Comment: @Kartik please visit any stall of the Gita Press and check which particular version suits you the most,The Hindi one by Sri Ramasukhadasji is beautiful.

Comment: @Kartik Tomstudy in English, the Gita by Swami Swarupananda published by the Advaita Ashrama is good.

Comment: Thank you sir. Please tell me. Can a person from any more of material nature worship Lord Krishna?

Comment: @Kartik yes of course. God is especially for people like you and me.